# Using 'the silver searcher' over SSH

Tags: ssh, arch-linux

I would like to run the silver searcher over ssh. However, for some unknown reason to me, the command never returns.

```
ssh domain.top 'ag -l test'
```

When I log into the server while the command is running, I get the following information:

```
ps aux | grep [a]g
username  16370  0.0  0.0  13432  1148 ?        Ss   21:40   0:00 ag -l test
```

Although much slower (I suppose), the following command is equivalent and works perfectly fine:

```
ssh domain.top 'find . -type f -exec grep -l -m 1 test {} \;'
```

My computer is running macOS High Sierra.
The server is running Arch Linux.
The silver searcher version is 2.1.0

Any thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The silver searcher needs a pseudo-terminal. Add `-t` to the ssh command.